# Event:4005 The Windows log-on process has unexpectedly terminated

Tags: windows-server-2012, login, windows-event-log, remote-desktop-services, rds

We have 3 RDS 2012 R2 hosts setup in our network, they are all stand alone session hosts. In the last month or so the WinLogin process has been crashing and causing people to not be able to log in.

More often than not, it happens on a Friday morning, though the last one happened Friday night early sat morning. It does not affect all servers at the same time it is completely random.  The way i fix it is to force shut down the VM and start it back up.

If users are already logged in it does not affect them, just new logon attempts fail (from users or processes).

I get the same event all the time:

**The Windows log-on process has unexpectedly terminated.**

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
 <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon" Guid="{DBE9B383-7CF3-4331-91CC-
A3CB16A3B538}" EventSourceName="Winlogon" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="49152">4005</EventID> 
<Version>0</Version> 
<Level>2</Level> 
<Task>0</Task> 
<Opcode>0</Opcode> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-10-28T01:58:51.000000000Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>4249609</EventRecordID> 
<Correlation /> 
<Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
<Channel>Application</Channel> 
<Computer>MY-TS.dn.local</Computer> 
<Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
<Binary>CA080000</Binary> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

I am not really sure where to look for this one  - Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any scheduled scans, like antivirus?
How old are the network drivers?

Comment: @spacenomyous We run Webroot, it scans daily.  The Hyper-V host network drivers look to be out of date, I will try update those tonight.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any profile size limits in group policy? Or otherwise some limit in the available disk space that would be available for the user profile at login?

Comment: What resources are allocated to these virtual machines? How much vRAM? How many users per RDS server?

Comment: Do you have any third-party logon authentication modules (e.g. smart card etc.) installed? Are you on the latest Windows updates?

Comment: @Appleoddity we dont have any profile size limits or disk space limits.

Comment: @joeqwerty we have 32GB vRAM and 8 vCPU, neither go over 75%  We have 20-50 users per vm.  Originally we about 100 users on one vm with more resources but over the last year i have been splitting it out (not that we had any issues)

Comment: @LuckyLuke We use RDPGaurd to blacklist failed logins, but this just reads event logs and creates firewall rules.  All servers are up to date